# Is possible to establish a connection between a browser and a CMD/PowerShell process at browser launch?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I have been looking for a means of running external script/programs against events on a web page in a browser such as "On button Click" or "On Page change".

I am able to easily do this with the Dev Tools found in browsers. For example, in the console, I can override the default behaviour of `myImage` with this:

```
myImage.onclick = function() {
    alert('Hello World')
}
```

This is exactly what I need, but I have since then learnt that its 'officially' not possible to run scripts/programs belonging to the host machine. This seems to a be core security feature of JavaScript/Web browsers.

I am now looking for alternative means of doing the above

Is it possible to start a 'browsing session' at the terminal, something like 'test mode' or 'debugging mode', so that it is connected to the shell that launched it, this way I can write my code in the Dev Tools console:

```
myImage.onclick = function() {
    logTerminal('Button has been clicked!')     //possibly a custom function
}
```

and when the event triggers, the browser outputs a message to the terminal its connected to, `Button has been clicked!`. and I am free to respond to it at the terminal.

Searching around, I came across Selenium but its feature set seems to be limited (I may be wrong) compared to what I can do at the Dev Tools console. Selenium seems to be based on polling, where the Dev Tools are event driven. I am looking for an event driven solution.

Note: I am NOT looking to deploy this as a solution for a live website, I am merely looking to, only on my local machine, "hook" into user events, like click, on sites such as the BBC/Nasa, so I can efficiently run my own tools at the right time, rather relying on polling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!